# How to push the next date/time to array which fits around current date/times in array?

Tags: php, arrays

What I have so far: [Example to test](https://3v4l.org/jYpAE)

```
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600"); // 10 mins
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300"); // 5 mins
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:15:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:20:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600");

$alreadyChosenDates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300"); // 10 mins

function returnClosestTime($alreadyChosenDates, $dates){
    // Set an array called $closestTime that has the time difference and the key
    $closestTime = [null, null];

    // Check each element in array
    foreach($dates as $key => $date){
        foreach($alreadyChosenDates as $chosenDates){
            // Calculate difference between already chosen dates array and the dates array
            $diff = (strtotime($chosenDates["date"]) + $chosenDates["duration"]) - strtotime($date["date"]);
            if($diff < 0) $diff = $diff * -1; 

            // If $closestTime is empty, populate it
            if($closestTime[0] === null) $closestTime = [$diff, $key];

            // If $closestTime isn't empty and the current date's time difference
            // is smaller, populate $closestTime with the time difference and key
            else if($diff < $closestTime[0]) $closestTime = [$diff, $key];
        }
    }
    return $dates[$closestTime[1]];
}

$alreadyChosenDates[] = returnClosestTime($alreadyChosenDates, $dates);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($alreadyChosenDates);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am looking for help to adapt my current code so that it loops through the `$dates` array picking the earliest times however the times need to be able to fit around one and other. This needs to always work with one `$alreadyChosenDates` already picked. In my example code I've got `2016-02-18 02:05:00` with duration of `300`.

Expected outcome based on example code above:

```
// Already chosen date.....
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
)

// After first loop
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:10:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
)

// Next loop
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:10:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:20:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
)

// Next loop 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:10:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:20:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
)
```

Another example with different start time:

```
// Already chosen date.....
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
)

// After first loop
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
)

// Next loop
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:15:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
)

// Next loop 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:15:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
)
```

Comment: This looks interesting?

Comment: Just that I understand what you're trying to accomplish, you are trying to pick elements from an array in a specific order, which means you need a sorting algorithm. This seems kind of like a basic question, not one that deserves a bounty. I'm also not sure what you mean with "the times need to be able to fit around one and other", do you mean that the timespans can overlap?

Comment: This answer does not get the 'most optimal adject dateRnges'. ;-/ It just uses `start dates` as being closest. Working on an answer that finds the 'best use of the time' between provided chosen dates. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243234/algorithm-to-find-the-maximum-sum-in-a-sequence-of-overlapping-intervals

Comment: I have a version that finds the most optimal list of dates between given date ranges. i.e. the longest none overlapping sequence of dates. see: http://eval.in/678367. I will update this answer with details of how it works tomorrow. I will update this answer to make it easy to get the code for now.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Thanks for all your time on improving this :) This is a really good release of code.

Comment: @RyanVincent  Can your code be changed to do something like this? - http://pastebin.com/kDnaejNX

Comment: @RyanVincent the start date will be passed in as a variable...then will have to work out which one matches that start date in the list of dates and that will be the start of the chosen dates. Also the children can only have one slot booked per a meeting... Hope this makes sense to you?

Comment: @RyanVincent Hey Ryan, have you had any chance to take a further look at what I'd like to further achieve with this?

Comment: @RyanVincent - Thanks. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @RyanVincent - I'm in the progress of changing a few things around with your code which you've given me previously. Have a look at my progress....

http://pastebin.com/xNCvxZbN

Comment: @RyanVincent - Going through the code, I have no idea what the `__construct()` and `__get()` is needed for?

Comment: @RyanVincent - Further change: Now changed it to use objects not arrays - http://pastebin.com/KHbb2fnA

Comment: Here is a `TimeSlot` object I am using. It can have as many extra attributes as required. It can be created from object or arrays. The attributes cab be accessed via array or property syntax, It should be useful. see: https://eval.in/682330.

Comment: Here is a program that uses all the classes. It still only does 'brute force search'. https://eval.in/682353. I will be changing the TimeSlotRange class to use: `dynamic programming, weighted interval`, At which point it should be quick enough to handle large numbers of time slots. Sources: [TimeSlot](http://pastebin.com/k4fQnUMa), [TimeSlotRange](http://pastebin.com/9hbgjE02) and [TimeSlotList - validation and run all ranges](http://pastebin.com/zuvfVPBJ)

Comment: @RyanVincent Cheers for everything but would you be able to throw together an example which uses this data http://pastebin.com/QkUXRwq7 and have the example out put the same as we've been doing but now show '1 meeting per child' so example if there was two children in 'grade_id = 87' and there was two meetings with 'grade_id = 87' show best meeting slot for the children...but it may only be able to give 2 meeting slots for one child and 1 meeting slot for the other. So 1 meeting has both children selected but the other only has 1 child selected. If you have any questions please ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirements

Input:
   1) given a list of 'chosen' dates
   2) A list of 'candidate' dates

Output:
 1) A 'final list of 'none-overlapping' dates

Where:

a) The first 'chosen' data is a 'start' date
     i.e. All candidate dates must be on or after this date.

b) No date ranges must overlap.

#### Update 1 - Provide 'Setter's and Process 'edge cases

1) `setter`s provided :

```
`setChosen(array $chosenDates)`

`setCandidates(array $candidateDates)`
```

2) Edge cases of missing inputs tested for.

3) Passing arrays via the `constructor` is optional.

#### Update 2 - Search for a list of optimal non-overlapping dates within a date range.

**Demonstration:** https://eval.in/678371

**Class source**: http://pastebin.com/K81rfytB

- It finds the list by doing a `brute force` search of all the dates within a given date range.

todo: convert the 'brute force search' to 'dynamic programing; by adding 'memoization'. It should not be difficult to do as it uses a 'decision tree' currently.

I will update this answer with instructions about is later. For now see the 'demo' link above.

#### Original Answer

*Demonstration:*

- [User supplied data and the results at 'eval.in'](https://eval.in/676231)
- [Updated with setters and edge case processing](https://eval.in/677457)

#### Explanation (or how I thought about it)

If the lists are sorted by 'start date' then it is quite easy to reason about the list of dates.

a) The first start date after the 'chosen start' date must be the closest.

I can immediately detect whether the next date `overlaps` with ones already selected.

So, Sorting the lists is useful.

To make the code which checks for overlapping easier I decided to convert the candidate dates' to a standard format that includes the 'range' or `window` of each 'candidate' as 'epoch seconds (unix timestamp)'. It makes the tests clearer?

The output must not contain *any overlapping candidate dates*.

That is what the class provided does.

#### the Class (`ScheduleList`) that does all the work

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Class that does all the work...
 */

/* 
 *  Requirements:
 *   
 *    Input:  
 *        1) given a list of 'chosen' dates
 *        2) A list of 'candidate' dates
 *         
 *    Output:
 *      1) A 'final list of 'none-overlapping' dates
 *
 *         Where: 
 *           a) The first 'chosen' data is a 'start' date
 *              i.e. All candidate dates must be on or after this date.
 *
 *           b) No date ranges must ovevlap.  
 */  

class ScheduleList
{
    /**
    * A list of all the dates that:
    *   1) After the 'chosen' start date
    *   2) Do not overlap with any 'chosen' date
    * 
    * @var array $candidates
    */
    private $candidates = array();    

    /**
    * Any date record we didn't use.
    * 
    * @var array $unused
    */
    public $unused = array();

    /**
    * List of dates that must be included in the 'final' list.
    * The earliest date is assumed to be a start date and everything must be later.
    * 
    * @var array $chosen
    */    
    private $chosen = array();

    /**
    * Ordered list of `none overlapping' dates from the chosen and candidates
    * 
    * @var array $final
    */    
    public $final = array();

    /**
    * These are the date lists.
    * They will be converted, sorted and filters as required.
    * 
    * @param array $chosenDates
    * @param array $candidateDates
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(array $chosenDates = array(),
                                array $candidateDates = array())
    {
        if (!empty($chosenDates)) {
            $this->setChosen($chosenDates);
        }

        if (!empty($candidateDates)) {
            $this->setCandidates($candidateDates);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Convert chosen dates to date range and sort them
    * 
    * @param array $chosenDates
    */
    public function setChosen(array $chosenDates)
    {
        // convert and sort 
        foreach ($chosenDates as $when) {    
            $this->chosen[] = $this->makeDateRange($when);
        }

        if (count($this->chosen) > 1) { // sort them so we can easily compare against them
            usort($this->chosen, 
                  function ($when1, $when2) {
                  return $when1['startTime'] - $when2['startTime'];
                  });  
        } 
    }

    /**
    * setter for candidates - will convert to date range
    * 
    * @param array $candidateDates 
    * 
    * @return void;
    */
    public function setCandidates(array $candidateDates)
    {
        // convert, sort and filter the candidates
        $this->convertCandidates($candidateDates);        
    }


    /**
    * Add the candidates to the final list
    *
    *   Known conditions:
    *     o  Both lists are in start date order 
    *     o  No candidates overlap with any chosen date 
    *     o  The candidates may overlap with each other - Hmm... need to check... 
    * 
    *  Note: The '$this->isOverlapsAny' method - as it is used a lot will be expensive (O(n^2))
    *        I can think of ways to reduce that - will happen when it is  refactored ;-/
    * 
    * @return array
    */
    public function generateList()
    { 
        if (empty($this->chosen) && empty($this->candidates)) {
            throw new \Exception('Generate Schedule: no input provided: ', 500);
        }   


        $this->final = $this->chosen;

        // first candidate MUST be the closest to the first chosen date due to sorting.
        $this->final[] = array_shift($this->candidates); // move it to the final list


        // Add the remaining candidates checking for overlaps as we do so...
        foreach ($this->candidates as $candidate) {
            if ($this->isOverlapAny($candidate, $this->final)) {
                $this->unused[] = $candidate;

            } else {                
                $this->final[] = $candidate;
            }
        }

        // sort final by start times - makes it easy to reason about
        usort($this->final, 
              function ($when1, $when2) {
                    return $when1['startTime'] - $when2['startTime'];
              });

        return $this->final;       
    }


   /**
    * Convert each date to a dateRange that is easier to check and display
    * 
    * o Check each candidate date for ovelapping with any of the 'chosen dates'
    * o Check if before first chosen start data. 
    */
    public function convertCandidates(array $candidateDates)
    {
        foreach ($candidateDates as $idx => $when) {    
            $candidate = $this->makeDateRange($when);

            // overlaps with any chosen then ignore it
            if ($this->isOverlapAny($candidate, $this->chosen)) { // ignore it
                $this->unused[] = $candidate;  // record failed ones so easy to check
                continue;    
            }

            // ignore if before first chosen start time 
            if (!empty($this->chosen) && $candidate['endTime'] <= $this->chosen[0]['startTime']) {
                $this->unused[] = $candidate;   // record failed ones so easy to check
                continue;    
            }

            $this->candidates[] = $candidate;
        }

        // sort candidates by start times - makes it easy to reason about
        usort($this->candidates, 
              function ($when1, $when2) {
                 return $when1['startTime'] - $when2['startTime'];
              });
    }         

    /**
     * Convert to UNIX timestamp as seconds will make the calculations easier 
     * 
     * The result has:
     *   1) the time as a date object - I can do calculations / format it whatever 
     *   2) startTime as epoch seconds 
     *   3) endTime as epoch seconds 
     * 
     * @param array $when
     * 
     * @return array  
     */
    public function makeDateRange(array $when)
    {
        $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $when['date']);
        $result = array();
        $result['when']   = $dt;
        $result['duration'] = (int) $when['duration'];
        $result['startTime']  = (int) $dt->format('U');
        $result['endTime']  = (int) $result['startTime'] + $when['duration'];

        return $result;            
    }

    /**
     * if start is after other end OR end is before other start then they don't overlap
     * 
     * Easiest way is to check that they don't overlap and reverse the result
     */ 
    public function isOverlap($when1, $when2)
    { 
        return ! (    $when1['endTime'] <= $when2['startTime']
                   || $when1['startTime'] >= $when2['endTime']);
    }

    /**
    * Check if candidate overlaps any of the dates in the list
    * 
    * @param array $candidate
    * @param array $whenList  -- list of non-overlapping dates
    * 
    * @return boolean  true if overlaps
    */
    function isOverlapAny($candidate, $whenList)
    {
        foreach ($whenList as $when) {
            if ($this->isOverlap($when, $candidate)) { // ignore it
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }   

    /**
    * Show a date formatted for debugging purposes
    * 
    * @param array $when
    * @return void
    */
    public function displayWhen(array $when)
    {
        echo PHP_EOL, 'date: ',   $when['when']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                      ' len: ',   $when['duration'],
                      ' end: ',   date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $when['endTime']),
                      ' start: ',  $when['startTime'], 
                      ' end: ',    $when['endTime']; 
    } 

    /*
     *  `Getters` so you can see what happened
     */
    public function getChosen()     { return $this->chosen; }
    public function getUnused()     { return $this->unused; }
    public function getCandidates() { return $this->candidates; }
    public function getFinal()      { return $this->final; }

    /**
    * properties - for those of us that like them 
    */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }        
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Run it

- Create an instance of the `ScheduleList` by passing the `chosen` array and the 'dates' array.
- The `generateList();` method will return the 'final' none-overlapping dates array.

Code:

```
$datesListGenerator = new ScheduleList($alreadyChosenDates,
                                       $dates);
$final = $datesListGenerator->generateList();
```

#### Update: Run with setters:

```
$datesListGenerator = new ScheduleList();

$datesListGenerator->setChosen($alreadyChosenDates);
$datesListGenerator->setCandidates($dates);
```

#### Various Outputs

#### makeDakeRange is now a public function:

```
var_dump('public makeDateRange : ', $datesListGenerator->makeDateRange(array('date'      => '2016-04-01 08:09:10',
                                                  'duration'  => 1)));

array (size=4)
  'when' => 
    object(DateTime)[83]
      public 'date' => string '2016-04-01 08:09:10' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  'duration' => int 1
  'startTime' => int 1459498150
  'endTime' => int 1459498151
```

#### Final (none-overlapping with any candidate input)

code:

```
echo PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, 'Final List';
foreach ($final as $when) {
    $datesListGenerator->displayWhen($when);
}
```

output:

```
Final List
date: 2016-02-18 02:05:00 len: 300 end: 2016-02-18 02:10:00 start: 1455761100 end: 1455761400
date: 2016-02-18 02:10:00 len: 600 end: 2016-02-18 02:20:00 start: 1455761400 end: 1455762000
date: 2016-02-18 02:20:00 len: 600 end: 2016-02-18 02:30:00 start: 1455762000 end: 1455762600
date: 2016-02-18 02:30:00 len: 600 end: 2016-02-18 02:40:00 start: 1455762600 end: 1455763200
```

#### Unused (Before start or Overlap)

Code:

```
echo PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, 'Unused List';
echo PHP_EOL, 'will be before first Chosen or Overlaps with one in the  final list...', PHP_EOL;
foreach ($datesListGenerator->getUnused() as $when) {
    $datesListGenerator->displayWhen($when);
}
```

Output:

```
Unused List
will be before first Chosen or Overlaps with one in the final list...

date: 2016-02-18 02:00:00 len: 600 end: 2016-02-18 02:10:00 start: 1455760800 end: 1455761400
date: 2016-02-18 02:05:00 len: 300 end: 2016-02-18 02:10:00 start: 1455761100 end: 1455761400
date: 2016-02-18 02:15:00 len: 300 end: 2016-02-18 02:20:00 start: 1455761700 end: 1455762000
date: 2016-02-18 02:25:00 len: 300 end: 2016-02-18 02:30:00 start: 1455762300 end: 1455762600
```

Comment: I will try and answer any queries.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I've been looking for this for a long time :)

Comment: @ChrisBeckett, Thanks. glad you found it useful. :)

Comment: Ryan would you be able to edit your code to work without `__construct` and `__get` can it work different way? also without using `public` and `protected`?

Comment: also do you know why it only shows two results in final when I create class file then declare the class in different php file?

Comment: You can access the 'private properties to see them whenever you wish as I provide the 'magic __get($name)' function. This you can use for debugging as in: `$instance->unsused;`  eyc.